# disable #pragma message("...") in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pragma

I am consuming a header file that's peppered with annoying messages like:

```
// annoying.h:

#pragma message("Compiling " __FILE__ )
```

I would prefer a clean build output when there are no actual problems.  Is there anything I can do before I include this file to stop the messages from being printed?

```
// not_annoying.cpp:

// PUT MAGIC HERE
#include "annoying.h"
```

Comment: The header is delivered from another group; it seems imprudent to manually change it every time.  However I did consider a pre-build step that runs it through `sed`.

Answer (score 8):

Just define a macro that makes the `message` pragma disappear.

```
#define message(ignore)
```

Comment: So it's legal to have a line that just says "#pragma" on it?  Unfortunately I can't use this because the token 'message' is used for other things too -- obviously what I really have is an organizational problem rather than a technical one.  But it's a pity there's not just a meta-pragma of some kind!

Comment: The behavior of pragmas is already implementation-defined, so the effect of the empty pragma is also implementation-defined. It is technically legal (6.10.6.1), but who knows what it does!

Comment: @Eric: Note that `#define message(ignore)` will define a *function macro* named `message`, not a general macro.  That is, it will substitute against a `message()` site but not against a plain `message` one.  Also, if you want to limit the scope of the macro, you could `#undef` it after including the problematic header.